# JAVA, Switch case takes two entries to work

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement

So I am making a text based adventure game in JAVA at the moment. I am having a minor issue with my code, which is making the gameplay of the game very annoying. When the player inputs a command, like "go north", the first time it works fine. But the second time, it doesn't work. It doesn't display my default switch case, so it DOES recognize the command. When I enter the same command, for example, "go north", again, it works. So it doesn't work the first time, but just entering it one more time makes it work. Is there a way I can make it so it doesn't need two inputs for it to work? 
Here's my code:

```
//// USER INPUT TIME ////

System.out.println(">_");
playerCommand = input.nextLine();
loop: while (loopInt > 0) {
    switch (input.nextLine()) {
    case "go north":
    case "n":
        alleywayGoNorth();
        break loop;
    case "go south":
    case "s":
        alleywayGoSouth();
        break loop;
    case "open door":
    case "o door":
        alleywayOpenDoorLocked();
        break loop;
    default:
        System.out.println("That command is not valid at the moment.");
        break;
    }
} 

////////
```

Comment: You are reading input twice. `playerCommand = input.nextLine();` reads  the first line. `switch (input.nextLine())` reads the next line. I suggest you move `playerCommand = input.nextLine();` into the while loop then change the switch to `switch (playerCommand)`

Comment: Removing your `loop:` label will cause the `while` loop to continue executing (assuming `loopInt` is greater than 0). I guess this means using `break` with a label on a loop causes you to break out of the whole loop, which it looks like you don't want.

Comment: @mdl , that is actually what I want. Without the loop: and the break loop; it will won't ask for user input again the next time. It will just run my default case.

Comment: @user3207994 Just so I'm clear... You want the user to be prompted over and over for commands, right? And currently your problem is that the first time you enter a command nothing happens? If I understood that right, this is because of the `playerCommand = input.nextLine()` line. The user enters input, which is stored in `playerCommand`, and then you don't do anything with it; instead you prompt a second time at the `switch` statement. I suggest you remove the `loop:` label, and remove the `playerCommand` line.

Comment: @mdl that does work, almost! The only problem is on the first time it loads up the user input, it will play my default case automatically. I can input after this, though, and I never see that automatic default case again. :D Let me tinker with it, I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @mdl Okay, so I have made no progress on getting the default case to not automatically run. Any ideas? :| Here's a screen of my code: http://gyazo.com/069a173a2d34025e37efa1621fcd58be.png

Notice I had to comment out my default case's sysout? I don't have that problem on any other switch cases except this first one.

Comment: @user3207994 How is `input` initialized? FWIW I used `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` to test your program, and I don't hit that default case first like you said happens. Are you hitting 'enter' before you enter valid commands?

Comment: @mdl I was not hitting enter beforehand, BUT I had an even earlier input asking for the name that had an extra sysout. Getting rid of that and the input worked! :) Thanks for your help. My code works the way it should now.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your for loop is wrong. Change the `switch (input.nextLine())` to `switch (playerCommand)` and then add `playerCommand = input.nextLine()` at the end of the switch statement. Also, remove all of references to your loop in your break statements.

Comment: This method doesn't work. When I do that, it automatically outputs my default case twice, doesn't even wait for input.

Comment: That's not possible. input.readLine() is a blocking call so it the program won't move past it until some input is given. What is your loopInt variable? Where does it come from?

Comment: loopInt is just an int I have set in my Variables.java file. This main class, which this switch case is in, extends Variables. loopInt is 100, so it is always greater than 0 as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Your lines are "staggered" by one, because you retrieve the input twice.

Change:

```
switch (input.nextLine()) {
```

to

```
switch (playerCommand) {
```

Comment: Nope. That makes my default case print to the screen indefinitely :c

Comment: I assume that's because your default cause does `break` instead of `break loop`.

Comment: I do that because if the user inputs an invalid command, I want it to look back to the beginning of the loop so they can try again. The ones that have break loop work, therefor sending them away from the loop and into a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the input of the player two times. Once when you initialize the "playerCommand" and once when you create the switch statement. Remove the playerCommand initialization and replace it into the switch statement.

```
switch(playerCommand = input.nextLine()) {
    ...
}
```

If you do not still need the "playerCommand" variable, you can use:

```
switch(input.nextLine()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Neither of those work. Both of them lead to my Switch running the default case without waiting for input.